# Populating a FormView with custom queryset

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'd like to set the logged in user's data to a profile form. Why isn't the below view populating the model form?

```
class UpdateProfile(FormView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.model.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.id)

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'company', 'title']
```

All my fields end up empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For single object views, you need to override `get_object` and use an `UpdateView`.

So to get the logged in user you could do:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView

class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = ProfileForm

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: That's beautiful. How come people don't like CBV?

Comment: CBVs can get confusing and limited when you want to make a lot of custom actions and it puts people off. Sites like https://ccbv.co.uk/ help as they make it easier to see what methods are available through which built in views.  Books like two scoops of Django go some way to help describe different approaches to CBVs and articles such as https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/03/21/class-based-views-vs-function-based-views.html do a good job of showing them vs function based views